# Create @font-face from existing font-faces

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

A client is hosting a premium font with a rotating file name (no hot linking). They provide me a CSS file with font-face definitions for each of the fonts. Unfortunately they created different font-face for each of the states. Is it possible for me merge these font-faces into a single, more usable font-face?

Here is what their CSS looks like:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom light font";
    src:url("fonts/ae1656aa-5f8f-4905-aed0-93e667bd6e4a.eot?iefix") format("eot");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom light font";
    src:url("fonts/ae1656aa-5f8f-4905-aed0-93e667bd6e4a.eot?iefix");
    src:url("fonts/530dee22-e3c1-4e9f-bf62-c31d510d9656.woff") format("woff"),url("fonts/688ab72b-4deb-4e15-a088-89166978d469.ttf") format("truetype"),url("fonts/7816f72f-f47e-4715-8cd7-960e3723846a.svg#7816f72f-f47e-4715-8cd7-960e3723846a") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom font";
    src:url("fonts/b7693a83-b861-4aa6-85e0-9ecf676bc4d6.eot?iefix") format("eot");}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom font";
    src:url("fonts/b7693a83-b861-4aa6-85e0-9ecf676bc4d6.eot?iefix");
    src:url("fonts/bcf54343-d033-41ee-bbd7-2b77df3fe7ba.woff") format("woff"),url("fonts/b0ffdcf0-26da-47fd-8485-20e4a40d4b7d.ttf") format("truetype"),url("fonts/da09f1f1-062a-45af-86e1-2bbdb3dd94f9.svg#da09f1f1-062a-45af-86e1-2bbdb3dd94f9") format("svg");
}   
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom medium font";
    src:url("fonts/07fe0fec-b63f-4963-8ee1-535528b67fdb.eot?iefix") format("eot");}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom medium font";
    src:url("fonts/07fe0fec-b63f-4963-8ee1-535528b67fdb.eot?iefix");
    src:url("fonts/60be5c39-863e-40cb-9434-6ebafb62ab2b.woff") format("woff"),url("fonts/4c6503c9-859b-4d3b-a1d5-2d42e1222415.ttf") format("truetype"),url("fonts/36c182c6-ef98-4021-9b0d-d63122c2bbf5.svg#36c182c6-ef98-4021-9b0d-d63122c2bbf5") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom bold font";
    src:url("fonts/c07fef9e-a934-42d7-92ad-69205f2b8a00.eot?iefix") format("eot");}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom bold font";
    src:url("fonts/c07fef9e-a934-42d7-92ad-69205f2b8a00.eot?iefix");
    src:url("fonts/14ff6081-326d-4dae-b778-d7afa66166fc.woff") format("woff"),url("fonts/8fda1e47-19be-46c7-8d83-8d4fb35572f0.ttf") format("truetype"),url("fonts/f751c8ae-1057-46d9-8d74-62592e002568.svg#f751c8ae-1057-46d9-8d74-62592e002568") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom extra bold font";
    src:url("fonts/b26ccb58-f2e3-47aa-a83a-02861bf54862.eot?iefix") format("eot");}
@font-face{
    font-family:"custom extra bold font";
    src:url("fonts/b26ccb58-f2e3-47aa-a83a-02861bf54862.eot?iefix");
    src:url("fonts/74649485-cd74-443e-9d54-331ccd448900.woff") format("woff"),url("fonts/feb77f4f-9e6b-4f88-909a-66199fd402ed.ttf") format("truetype"),url("fonts/2e490192-e531-4236-9c55-90daaad4a34e.svg#2e490192-e531-4236-9c55-90daaad4a34e") format("svg");
}
```

As you can see this is very frustrating to work with. The file names change seemingly daily. I've tried to get them to update it but they have slow turn around so it may be a while.

Comment: To give you a good answer it would be helpful to have a better idea of why using the official stylesheet is a problem. Just because a font-face is declared doesn't mean you have to use it or even that the browser will download it.

Comment: The problem is the font-familys all have different names so it is not simply a matter of adding the font-weight to the class. As it stands now, I need to add a new font family everytime I want to change the font weight or style. Normally I would do this with a simple class similar to what you suggested in the comments but I inherited some css from my predecessors with !important everywhere defining the font-families. I'm just going to have to create a new set of rules using the class-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

A font's default "boldness" is a property of it's design. Internally these font faces are all physically different shapes.

It sounds like the bold/light/italic variations aren't that important to you so all you really need to do is delete every font declaration except "custom font" then override the boldness like a normal font:

```
.myregularfont {
    font-family:"custom font";
    font-weight: normal;
}
.myboldfont {
    font-family:"custom font";
    font-weight: bold; /* Browser will create faux-font for bold custom font */
}
.myboldfontcrisp {
    font-family:"custom font bold"; /* Awesome, browser doesn't have to create a faux-font, just download bold variant instead */
}
```

This works because your browser will create **lower quality** "faux-bold" and "faux-italic" versions of the font as needed.

So by not importing the original bold and italic variations of the font the resulting fonts will not look as good as the formal versions in your original stylesheet but it does solve your "problem" of having lots of @font-face declarations.

See this article for more details on "faux" fonts: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles

Comment: I think you're missing the point. It sounds to me like the author actually wants to edit the font files so that he can use the same font name in his CSS and just change the `font-weight` CSS property to get the light, medium, bold, extra bold versions.

Comment: I'm not missing the point at all. That's exactly what my answer provides. Of course he will have to manually or automatically edit the CSS file every time it's updated but that isn't the problem being presented.

Comment: I get that he wants to alias an existing font-face but you can't (without scripting). My answer provides an alternative.

Comment: Why does he need an alternative? If the font files are written correctly (so that they are all of the same family) all he needs to do is make sure the font names in the `@font-face` declaration are the same, and declare a `font-weight` in each `@font-face` declaration

Comment: My bad, I obviously misunderstood the point of the question. I was wondering why the OP was using "custom font" and "custom bold font", and provided an answer on how to use the same identifier with a different `font-weight` but you are correct, the OP actually wanted to import fewer declarations, which is, of course, not possible.

Comment: The problem with this whole question is I'm not convinced the author is solving a real problem. From a technical standpoint just linking the provided stylesheet "as-is" is a superior arrangement since it allows the browser to render cleaner bold/italic text with practically no downside. However I've learned it's better on SO just to answer the question asked rather than speculate on why it's important.

Comment: I'll just have to take this class approach. It will mean I have to change a lot of existing CSS and markup that I inherited. If the font-face was set up properly in the beginning or the class approach was taken in the beginning, it would have solved itself.